# Matrix and vector multiplication

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Find all real numbers $k$ for which there exists a nonzero, 2-dimensional vector $v$ such that
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 12 \\ 2 & -3 \end{pmatrix}v = kv.
$$

Comment: Have you seen eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about this is to write $$kv = \begin{pmatrix} k & 0 \\ 0 & k \end{pmatrix}$$
and subtract it from sides to get
$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 - k & 12 \\ 2 & -3-k \end{pmatrix}v = 0$$
Now this question becomes about the null space of the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 - k & 12 \\ 2 & -3-k \end{pmatrix}$$
For which non-zero values of $k$ does this matrix have a non-zero null space? Try some sort of argument using with the determinant